# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?

Tags: java, java-swing, maven, apache-poi, netbeans-11.3

Tengo un proyecto en NetBeans donde utilizo bibliotecas de apache poi para procesar archivos de excel, implementando java swing también. El problema es que al ejecutar mi programa en el IDE todo lo hace bien, pero cuando genero el .jar y lo ejecuto desde la consola lanza:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
```

Éstas son las dependencias de mi pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mx.com.</groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>mx.com.view.JFWindow</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>        
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <name></name>
</project>
```

¿Qué podría estar pasando?

¿Cómo puedo solucinarlo?

Comment: Debes hacer un fat-jar si quieres usar librerías externas en él. Es decir, basicamente le metes todas las librerías dentro a tu JAR para que estén disponibles sin necesidad de tener múltiples JAR en la carpeta. Puedes revisar [esta respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222971/14083367) donde explica cómo hacerlo

Comment: Echa un vistazo a este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320849/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-poi-ss-usermodel-workbook/48299944).